# Angualr, List is not loading dynamically with observable list

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

I am trying to make a quiz app where questions with answerrs will be given to the admin.The list is not loading dynamically.What i want is after the questioin is added the list will show automaticlly without me manually realoding.
this is question model:

```
export class QuestionModel {
    questionId: number = 0;
    questionInWords: string = "";
    option1: string = "";
    option2: string = "";
    option3: string = "";
    option4: string = "";
    answer: number = 0;

}
```

this is the crud service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { QuestionModel } from '../Models/Question';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {

  readonly rootUrl = environment.rootUrl;

  idForEdit: number = NaN;
  dataForEdit!: any;
  list: QuestionModel[] = [];
  showPopup: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: Router) { }
  addQuestion(body: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/Question/AddQuestion/', body);
  }
  deleteQuestion(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(this.rootUrl + '/Question/delete?id=' + id);
  }
  EditQuestion(id: number, body: any) {
    return this.http.put(this.rootUrl + '/Question/editQuestion?id=' + id, body);
  }
  showAQuestion(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/Question/getAQuestion?id=' + id);
  }
  refreshList(): Observable<QuestionModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<QuestionModel[]>(this.rootUrl + '/Question/GetAll');
  }
}
```

this is admin component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgToastService } from 'ng-angular-popup';
import { CrudService } from 'src/app/Services/crud.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-dashbord',
  templateUrl: './admin-dashbord.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-dashbord.component.css']
})
export class AdminDashbordComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public crudService: CrudService,
    private toast: NgToastService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  addForm!: FormGroup;
  editForm!: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getallQues();
  }
  getallQues() {
    this.crudService.refreshList()
      .subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
          this.crudService.list = data;
        },
      })
  }
  showPopupButton() {
    this.crudService.showPopup = true;
  }

  callEditQuestion(id: number) {
    this.crudService.idForEdit = id;
    this.showPopupButton();
  }
  callDeleteQuestion(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    this.crudService.deleteQuestion(id).subscribe();
    this.toast.success({ detail: 'Success', summary: "DELETED", duration: 2000 })
  }

}
```

html for admin component

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div *ngIf="crudService.showPopup">
  <app-add-edit-popup></app-add-edit-popup>
</div>

<div class="flex-col justify-between p-20 max-w-full h-full">
  <div>
    <button
      class="flex justify-center cursor-pointe text-white bg-gray-900 hover:bg-purple-800 border-2 border-white p-2 my-4"
      (click)="showPopupButton()"
    >
      ADD A QUESTION
    </button>
  </div>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let qn of crudService.list; let i = index">
    <div
      class="flex justify-between w-full border-2 border-white bg-gray-900 text-white"
    >
      <div class="p-2 m-2">
        <span class="flex-end right-0">{{ i + 1 }}</span>
        <p>{{ qn.questionInWords }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex p-2 m-2 w-36 bg-blue-500">
        <button
          class="p-2 m-1 border-2 hover:bg-purple-800"
          (click)="callEditQuestion(qn.questionId)"
        >
          Edit
        </button>
        <button
          class="p-2 m-1 border-2 hover:bg-red-800"
          (click)="callDeleteQuestion(qn.questionId)"
        >
          delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="px-10 py-2 text-black">
      <ul>
        <li [ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-400 rounded-lg': qn.answer == 0 }">
          (A) {{ qn.option1 }}
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-400 rounded-lg': qn.answer == 1 }">
          (B) {{ qn.option2 }}
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-400  rounded-lg': qn.answer == 2 }">
          (C) {{ qn.option3 }}
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-400  rounded-lg': qn.answer == 3 }">
          (D) {{ qn.option4 }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>Ans: ({{ (qn.answer + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase() }})</div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

EDIT:
this is the add-edit comnponent :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgToastService } from 'ng-angular-popup';
import { CrudService } from 'src/app/Services/crud.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-popup',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-popup.component.css']
})
export class AddEditPopupComponent {




  constructor(
    public crudService: CrudService,
    private toast: NgToastService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }
  addEditForm!: FormGroup;
  inputButton: string = 'ADD';


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addEditForm = this.fb.group({
      questionId: 0,
      questionInWords: "",
      imageName: "",
      option1: "",
      option2: "",
      option3: "",
      option4: "",
      answer: "",
    });
    if (this.crudService.idForEdit) {
      this.populateEditForm()
      this.inputButton = 'UPDATE'
      console.log(this.addEditForm.value)
    }
  }
  OnSubmit() {
    if (!this.crudService.idForEdit) {
      if (this.addEditForm.valid) {
        console.log(this.addEditForm.value)
        this.crudService.addQuestion(this.addEditForm.value)
          .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              this.addEditForm.reset();
              //this.crudService.refreshList();
              this.crudService.showPopup = false;
              this.toast.info({ detail: 'SUCCESS!', summary: "ADDED", duration: 2000 })
            })
      }
    } else {
      if (this.addEditForm.valid) {
        console.log(this.addEditForm.value)
        this.crudService.editQuestion(this.addEditForm.value.questionId, this.addEditForm.value)
          .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              this.addEditForm.reset();
              //this.crudService.refreshList();
              this.crudService.showPopup = false;
              this.inputButton = 'ADD'
              this.toast.info({ detail: 'SUCCESS!', summary: "UPDATED", duration: 2000 })
            }
          )
      }
    }
  }
  populateEditForm() {

    this.crudService.showAQuestion(this.crudService.idForEdit)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.crudService.dataForEdit = data;
          this.addEditForm.controls['questionId'].setValue(data.questionId);
          this.addEditForm.controls['questionInWords'].setValue(data.questionInWords);
          this.addEditForm.controls['option1'].setValue(data.option1);
          this.addEditForm.controls['option2'].setValue(data.option2);
          this.addEditForm.controls['option3'].setValue(data.option3);
          this.addEditForm.controls['option4'].setValue(data.option4);
          this.addEditForm.controls['answer'].setValue(data.answer);
        }
      )
  }
  closePopup() {
    this.crudService.showPopup = false;
    this.crudService.idForEdit = NaN;
  }
```

I am using the observer, but it did not work.

Comment: Your `refreshList()` method will call your API, get the current question list and then finish. It will **not** recognize server side changes after it was completed. You can either implement some kind of handler for that (sockets, polling or similar) or manually update the question list after a changing CRUD operation.

Comment: As a slight aside the it’s normally bad practice to include /getAll /delete etc as part of the api endpoint. The request method defines this. So simpler to have endpoints /questions and /questions/:id. A good opinionated guide here: https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired behavior, I would suggest the following:

1. Change the questions list into a [behavioral subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) that exposes an observable.

Instead of:

```
list: QuestionModel[] = [];
```

I would have:

```
private questionsListSubject = new BehaviorSubject<QuestionModel[]>([]);

get questionsList$(): Observable<QuestionModel[]>{
   return this.questionsListSubject.asObservable();
}
```

2. Change the crud operations methods to **update your questions list** every time a change is made as follows:

```js
    addQuestion(body: any) {
        return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/Question/AddQuestion/', body).pipe(
          tap(v => {
            const questionsList = this.questionsListSubject.value;
            // Assuming your endpoint returns the added question
            questionsList.push(v);
            this.questionsListSubject.next(questionsList);
          })
       );
      }

      deleteQuestion(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete(this.rootUrl + '/Question/delete?id=' + id).pipe(
          tap(_ => {
            const questionsList = this.questionsListSubject.value;
    
            this.questionsListSubject.next(
                 questionsList.filter(question => question.id !== id)
            );
          })
       );
      }

      editQuestion(id: number, body: any) {
        return this.http.put(this.rootUrl + '/Question/editQuestion?id=' +id, body).pipe(
          tap(_ => {
             const updatedQuestions = this.questionsListSubject.value.map(question => question.id === id ? body : question);
            
            this.questionsListSubject.next(updatedQuestions);
          })
       );
      }

      showAQuestion(id: number) {
        return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/Question/getAQuestion?id=' + id);
      }

      refreshList(): Observable<QuestionModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<QuestionModel[]>(this.rootUrl + '/Question/GetAll').pipe(
          tap(questions => this.questionsListSubject.next(questions))
      );
      }
```

This makes sure that upon every CRUD operations, the UI gets updated data **without having to reload the page**.

3. Include the questions list observable in your **admin component** as follows:

```js
    addForm!: FormGroup;
    editForm!: FormGroup;
    questionsList$ = this.crudService.questionsList$;
```

4. Simplify the `getAllQues()` method in admin component to:

```js
      getallQues() {
        this.crudService.refreshList().subscribe()
      }
```

You no longer need to update the questions list here since it is done in the service.

5. Update you template to use the `questionsList$` observable as follows:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let qn of (questionsList$ | async); let i = index">
```

**Note**: Make sure you **subscribe everywhere you use the crud methods** so that the logic to update the questions list is executed.

Comment: 1.I did as you told adding question works fine .thanks
2. While deleting a question the list is not displaying rather only the question which user is trying to delete is dispalyed

Comment: editing question gives this error core.mjs:8506 
        
       ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at Object.next (crud.service.ts:71:59)
    at source.subscribe.isUnsub (tap.js:17:81)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at map.js:7:24
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at filter.js:6:128
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)

Comment: @AyanMondal there were some typos in the code. I edited the answer to fix the issues you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the type of `list` in your `CrudService` to type `BehaviorSubject<QuestionModel[]>`.

*Read more about the RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)*

```
export class CrudService {
  // ...
  list: BehaviorSubject<QuestionModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  // ...
}
```

In your component, you can use a class member to subscribe to this Behavior Subject as follows:

```
export class AdminDashbordComponent implements OnInit {
  // ...
  list = this.crudService.list.asObservable(); // Type Observable<QuestionModel[]>
  // ...
}
```

When you call the API, update your Behavior Subject

```
  getallQues() {
    this.crudService.refreshList()
      .subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
          this.crudService.list.next(data);
        },
      })
  }
```

And finally, to get the latest value in your HTML, you can use the `async` pipe.

*Read more about Angular's [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let qn of list | async; let i = index">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tried this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something once the call is complete

```
this.crudService.deleteQuestion(id).subscribe(() => {
  // Either call a full refresh from the server or
  this.crudService.list = this.crudService.list.filter(q => q.questionId !== id);
});
```

You would need to do this each time you call the server for add and edit as well.